# using java service wrapper and log4j

Tags: log4j, wrapper

I've been getting a problem to use java service wrapper and log4j, where I have the log service and another log (of the application) using log4j configuration.

The problem is that my service log (wrapper) is also writing the information in my log4j log, how can I solved that?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the file structure of your application and the log4j configuration file?

Comment: No, I can't cause is a private and comercial application. =(